# xrandr: can't open display

Tags: x11, raspberry-pi, armbian

I am having trouble with my [7-inch type C LCD screen](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)). 
When I try to display an application on it,
I get the error `Missing X server or $DISPLAY`. 
I use the command `xrandr` and get the message `can't open display`. 
I found some solutions for Raspberry,
but my Orange Pi lite board doesn't have `config.txt`.

I tried adding the line `disp_mode=1024x600p60` to armbianEnv.txt,
but that doesn't seem to be the solution. 
I currently use Armbian Minimal (a stripped-down version). 
Could that be the problem? 
`xrandr -display :0.0` returns `Can't open display :0.0`.

Comment: hi @Seamus i use armbian for orange pi lite it is a stripped down version, but i will try with Wayland

Comment: Hey, just a guess, but Armbian could be a problem. To me it sounds like either a driver or a hardware problem, not a configuration problem. But I have honestly little knowledge about `arm` and the surrounding environment.